# C++ internal compiler error

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compiler-errors

Since many weeks our compilation server is crashing randomly while compiling our C++ code.
Sometimes the compilation failed and we have the following error :

```
/usr/include/c++/7/future:429:7: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
```

The error is always raised from system libraries (but not always the same) and at different step of the compilation process.

We have tried to increase the size of RAM up to 10 GB and the size of the swap (up to 5GB) but the issue has not been solved. We have also tried multiple version  of the cc compiler but without success.

We have a set a machine but the issue is only reproducible on out compilation server. We have to fix it because this server is part of our continuous integration chain.

The source code is composed of  about 10000-20000 line of codes (not really much) but we use some template.

Does someone knows how to solve or investigate this error ?

System information:

```
compiler = c++ 
compiler version = c++ (Ubuntu 7.2.0-1ubuntu1~16.04) 7.2.0
compilation tools = cmake and make
ubuntu-xenial
RAM  = 10G
Swap = 5G
NbCPU = 4
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Try to exclude one external library after another from compilation and check if the error still happens after each modification. Linking doesn't matter when you can't get past compilation anyways.

Comment: What change did you make to the code to make the compiler to start failing? You *do* have some kind of source control system with logs (and diffs!) that you can check?

Comment: Maybe you have bad RAM?

Comment: @Jodocus: we have try that (and also using different version of our third parties (when possible)) but I believe the instabilities are related either to the code or to the system itself

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The compilation on the compilation server has never been stable. The error is happening like every 2 months (but the server is used every day).

Comment: @melpomene
Good idea, we will try to check RAM.

Comment: It really, really does sound like a hardware fault, indeed most likely RAM, though there are other possible sources of instability, e.g. noisy power. I'm guessing the machine has not been configured with ECC RAM (if it has, check the logs!) - if it is ultimately a hardware fault, I would very strongly recommend that any replacement hardware is indeed with ECC RAM etc.

Comment: You could try building other programs (e.g. FireFox). While it's known to stress a compiler, it's the sort of stress that a compiler should be able to dealw ith. And 10 GB is definitely sufficient for it. On a slightly unrelated note, your compiler probably is `gcc`. AFAIK there is no compiler known as just `cc`; that is more a convention to refer to the _local default_ compiler. And on Ubuntu, that default is GCC.

Comment: uhm, if it is an hardware problem, how can it manifest itself *only* as a compiler segfault ? you should observe occasional crashes in other processes too, as long as they have comparable memory usages ...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes — compilers are surprisingly effective stress tests. Linux kernel compilations used to constitute a good burn-in test of new hardware, and the recently confirmed AMD Ryzen CPU bug (see e.g. https://hothardware.com/news/amd-confirms-rare-ryzen-smt-bug-and-fix) was demonstrated only in parallel software builds.

Comment: Finally it seems it was hardware (RAM) issue but we just need some times to validate the solution

Comment: @melpomene we contact our venodr and he replace the bad RAM. Now every is running well. If you create the answer I can flag your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've got intermittent errors in (presumably well tested) compiler internals from (presumably also well tested) system libraries, and the problems are reproducible on multiple compiler versions, but only on this single machine. That points towards a hardware issue.

Bad RAM seems like a good candidate. A C++ compiler processing a moderately sized code base is likely to crash from e.g. random bit flips at least some of the time.

You should test your RAM (or just swap it out and see if the failures go away).